# How to observe a change in an NSManagedObject record from 2 different view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Basically I have a masterView Controller that has 3 containers at one point I am updating an NSManagedObject for instance: (Person.firstName = "Ehab")!

In the other 2 containers one has a property [Person] & the other has a property [Person: String] & both of those collection properties has the record that has been changed.

What I am looking for is that when I change a (Person.firstName = "taylor") I need the other 2 classes how has the array and dictionary to be notified about the change that has just happened!

One way is using NotoficationCenter and pass the modified object in the UserInfo. But is there an easier way to do that??

Comment: What about to create a protocol? For example, something calling ChangeDelegate with a func person(_ didChange: Person). The 2 other container delegating itself by using this protocol...

Comment: Its not a bad idea but I think notification is better in my case..

Answer (score 7):

Use `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`

In your 2 containers `viewDidLoad`, add an observer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: yourManagedObjectContext)


@objc func managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange(_ notification: Notification){
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {
        return
    }

    if let updates = userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> {
        for update in updates {
            if let person = update as? Person {
                // update person info here

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that helps.... Thought what I did is I setup a custom notification and I passed my updated object "After I saved the mangedContext". Then I replaced that one. I thought that might be a better approach for what I have. :)

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the **NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification** is the most common way and the easiest way to be notified about changes from a **NSManagedObjectContext**.
You can extracts from the userInfo dictionary the objects that were inserted, deleted or in your case updated.

But notice that you will be notified only when the **NSManagedObjectContext** saves.

Obviously, you'll have to register to this notification in all the view controllers where you want to manage your object and handle the notifications in these view controllers. There are plenty of documentations about this online and on Apple docs/sample codes.

Comment: I think what are you suggesting  about this is doable  with ** NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification**! But I think using NotificationCenter still going to be easeir or more readable. Thanks for your response! I appreciate that :)

Comment: Yeah of course, you'll have to register to this notification with a notification center. No problem.